# How use “+” instead of “%20” for spaces in query parameters

Tags: twig, urlencode

I have code:

```
{% set pageTitle = siteUrl('/search?keyword=' ~ query %}
```

return test test1

```
{% set pageTitle = siteUrl('/search?keyword=' ~ query|url_encode) %}
```

return test%20test1

```
{% set pageTitle = siteUrl('/search?keyword=' ~ query|url_encode(true)) %}
```

return test%20test1

How I can return test+test1 ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try `replace` filter ([Twig replace documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/replace.html)).

`{% set pageTitle = siteUrl('/search?keyword=' ~ query|url_encode|replace({'%20': '+'})) %}`